# Pipeline optimzation, is there any point to do this?

Tags: c++, optimization, assembly, cpu

Some very expencied programmer from another company told me about some low-level code-optimzation tips that targetting specific CPU, including pipeline-optimzation, which means, arrange the code (inlined assembly, obviously) in special orders such that it fit the pipeline better for the targetting hardware.

With the presence of out-of-order and speculative execuation, I just wonder is there any points to do this kind of low-level stuff? We are mostly invovled in high performance computing, so we can really focus on one very specific CPU type to do our optimzation, but I just dont know if there is any point to do this specific optimzation, anyone has any experience here, where to begin? are there any code examples for this kind of optimzation? many thanks!

Comment: An optimization like this can only be useful once you're absolutely sure you've exhausted all other optimizations (lock contention, atomic instructions, algorithmic complexity, etc.).

Comment: If the target CPU supports out-of-order instruction execution, then the short answer is almost certainly "no."  I think pipeline opts are useful for mobile platforms since those most oftten lack out-of-order execution.  (though soon to change with next-gen chips)

Comment: The answer is complicated, but in the general case it is "compare and find out".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll start by saying that the compiler will *usually* optimize code sufficiently (i.e. well enough) that you do not need to worry about this provided your high-level code and algorithms are optimized. In general, manual optimizing should only happen if you have hard evidence that there is an actual performance issue that you can quantify and have tracked down.

Now, with that said, it's always possible to improve things - sometimes a little, sometimes a lot.

If you are in the high-performance computing game, then this sort of optimization *might* make sense. There are all sorts of "tricks" that can be done, but they are best left to real experts and not for the faint of heart.

If you really want to know more about this topic, a good place to start is by reading [Agner Fog's website](http://www.agner.org/optimize/).

Comment: This. And more often than not, the compiler will do much better, not just sufficiently.

Comment: Actually *usually* is right.  It depends on what platform you're work on.  On some platforms, compilers tend to lag behind...

Comment: @Damon I think the whole "compiler will do much better" saying is rubbish. Optimizing better than a compiler isn't always trivial, but it certainly isn't exceedingly difficult -- _when that is your goal_. A compiler's advantage is that it'll optimize even the parts you don't really care about running fast -- the parts you might have let stay a bit slow and easy to understand if you were hand-writing them.

Comment: @CoryNelson: Maybe you're a much better coder than me. I've done this many times. You spend days to write a piece of code that slightly outperforms the compiler in a benchmark, only to find out that it runs slower in a real program. When you look, you find that the compiler did some really weird, non-obvious stuff with the result that it runs faster. At one time I needed to decode blocks of data (SSE code) and calculate a checksum. Turned out the compiler interleaved blocks and mixed instructions so SSE insns ran in parallel and the decoding was entirely "free", 100% faster than "optimized".

Comment: @Damon Interleaving stuff for free is a standard optimization that we do.  Not weird.  *Should* be obvious to an experienced assembly programmer.  Sounds like you may have gotten caught up in micro-optimization without considering the true goal of your code.  I agree that compilers generate better code than most people do though.  Optimizing by hand is best left to when you've run out of better algorithms, or when you just want to have fun.  :-)

Answer (score 3):

### Pipeline optimization will improve your programs performance:

Branches and jumps may force your processor to reload the instruction pipeline, which takes some time. This time could be devoted to data processing instructions.

### Some platform independent methods for pipeline optimizations:

1. Reduce number of branches.
2. Use Boolean Arithmetic
3. Set up code to allow for conditional execution of instructions.
4. Unroll loops.
5. Make loops have short content (that can fit in a processor's cache
   without loading).

### Edit 1: Other optimizations

1. Reduce code by eliminating features and requirements.
2. Review and optimize the design.
3. Review implementation for more efficient implementations.
4. Revert to assembly language only when all other optimizations have
   provided little performance improvement; optimize only the code that
   is executed 80% of the time; find out by profiling.

### Edit 2: Data Optimizations

You can also gain performance improvements by organizing your data.  Search the web for "Data Driven Design" or "Optimize performance data".

One idea is that the most frequently used data should be close together and ultimately fit into the processor's data cache.  This will reduce the frequency that the processor has to reload its data cache.

Another optimization is to: Load data (into registers), operate on data, then write all data back to memory.  The idea here is to trigger the processor's data cache loading circuitry before it processes the data (or registers).

If you can, organize the data to fit in one "line" of your processor's cache.  Sequential locations require less time than random access locations.

Answer (score 1):

There are always things that "help" vs. "hinder" the execution in the pipeline, but for most general purpose code that isn't highly specialized, I would expect that performance from compiled code is about as good as the best you can get without highly specialized code for each model of processor. If you have a controlled system, where all of your machines are using the same (or a small number of similar) processor model, and you know that 99% of the time is spent in this particular function, then there may be a benefit to optimizing that particular function to become more efficient.

In your case, it being HPC, it may well be beneficial to handwrite some of the low-level code (e.g. matrix multiplication) to be optimized for the processor you are running on. This does take some reasonable amount of understanding of the processor however, so you need to study the optimization guides for that processor model, and if you can, talk to people who've worked on that processor before.

Some of the things you'd look at is "register to register dependencies" - where you need the result of c = a + b to calculate x = c + d - so you try to separate these with some other useful work, such that the calculation of x doesn't get held up by the c = a + b calculation.

Cache-prefetching and generally caring for how the caches are used is also a useful thing to look at - not kicking useful cached data out that you need 100 instructions later, when you are storing the resulting 1MB array that won't be used again for several seconds can be worth a lot of processor time.

It's hard(er) to control these things when compilers decide to shuffle it around in it's own optimisation, so handwritten assembler is pretty much the only way to go.